# How to efficiently join in data from TFRecords in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord, tpu

I need to efficiently join in a small amount of data when training a TensorFlow model on `TFRecord`s. How can I do this lookup using information from the parsed `TFRecord`?

More details:

I am training a convolutional network on a large dataset using `TFRecords`. Each `TFRecord` contains the raw image along with the target label, and some metadata about the image. Part of the training is that I need to standardize the image using a `mean` and `std` that are specific to a grouping of images. To do this in the past I have hardcoded the `mean` and `std` into the `TFRecord`. It is then used like so in my `parse_example` which is used to map over the `Dataset` in my `input_fn`, like so:

```
def parse_example(..):
    # ...
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(value, keys_to_features)
    image_raw = tf.decode_raw(parsed['image/raw'], tf.uint16)
    image = tf.reshape(image_raw, image_shape)
    image.set_shape(image_shape)

    # pull hardcoded pixels mean and std from the parsed TFExample
    mean = parsed['mean']
    std = parsed['std']

    image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) - mean) / std

    # ...

    return image, label
```

While the above works and makes for fast training times it is limiting in that I often want to change what `mean` and `std` I use. Rather than writing the `mean` and `std` into the `TFRecord`s I would prefer to lookup the appropriate summary stats at training time. What this means is that when I train I have a small python dictionary that I can lookup the appropriate summary stats using information about the image that is parsed from the `TFRecord`. The problem I am running into is that I can't seem to use this python dictionary in my tensorflow graph. If I try to do the lookup directly it doesn't work because I have tensor objects instead of the actual primitives. This makes sense sine the `input_fn` is doing symbolic manipulation constructing the computation graph for TensorFlow (right?). How do I get around this?

One thing I have tried is to create a lookup table from a dictionary like so:

```
def create_channel_hashtable(keys, values, default_val=-1):
    initializer = tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values)
    return tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(initializer, default_val)
```

The hashtables can be created and used in the `parse_example` function to do a lookup. This all "works" but it prohibitively slows training down. It may be worth noting that this training is being done on TPUs. With the original approach of using values from the `TFRecord`s the training is very fast and isn't bottlenecked by IO, however this changes when the hash lookup is used.  What is the suggested way to handle these cases? While repackaging `TFRecord`s is doable it seems silly when the data to be looked up is small and could be made efficient.

Comment: The `input_fn` is actually running on CPU. Your training (`model_fn`) is done on TPU.  Is your vocabulary of `key` very large? I have worked on a similar problem as yours with a vocabulary of 5000. And I have no problem of IO bottleneck.  Can you share your entire code of `input_fn` so that the problem is reproducible?

Comment: @greeness My understanding was that it was running on the CPU.. does that mean though that I should be able to use a python dictionary? Or do I need to use a lookup table? To answer your question the size of the vocab lookup is small, it is only 204. When you have done it in the past have you used a `HashTable` or does it work with a python dictionary?

Comment: I was using the same hashTable. `index_table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
      tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
          tf.convert_to_tensor(families, dtype=tf.string),
          tf.convert_to_tensor(family_indices, dtype=tf.int64)), 0) .    family_indices = tf.map_fn(
      index_table.lookup, features['family'], dtype=tf.int64)`

Comment: Thanks @greeness, it is good to know that is is a workable approach. I have been debugging this and I think the actual problem is an unrelated regression in IO performance in my input_fn and/or the size of the tfrecords.  I'll close this question if that turns out to be the case. Thanks again for answering.

Answer (score 0):

This question kind of covers this topic:

[How can I merge multiple tfrecords file into one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265211/how-can-i-merge-multiple-tfrecords-file-into-one-file)

Seems like you would save the TFRecords to file and then use TFRecordDataset to pull them all out into one dataset. The code given in the answer to that above question i linked is this:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames_to_read,
    compression_type=None,    # or 'GZIP', 'ZLIB' if compress you data.
    buffer_size=10240,        # any buffer size you want or 0 means no buffering
    num_parallel_reads=os.cpu_count()  # or 0 means sequentially reading
)
```

Comment: The above seems to be reading a homogenous set of files into a dataset, something I'm already doing actually. This doesn't seem to address my need of joining in additional information. Each TFExample has a key that I want to use to lookup a value from at training time.